# How to get rid of unwanted spaces after using ToString() in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, object-to-string

This might be a problem with Session and not ToString(), I'm not sure.

I have two .aspx pages and I want to pass an IP address from a datatable from one page to the other.  When I do this, spaces get added that I don't want.  The simple version of the code is this:

first .aspx page

```
int num = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
DataView tempDV = SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;

Session["camera"] = tempDV.Table.Rows[num].ItemArray[2];
Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
```

test.aspx page

```
string ipCamAdd = Session["camera"].ToString();

TextBox1.Text = "http://" + ipCamAdd + "/jpg/image.jpg?resolution=320x240";
```

what I want to print is

```
http ://ipadd/jpg/image.jpg?resolution=320x240
```

but what prints out is

```
http//ipaddress      /jpg/image.jpg?resolution=320x240
```

how can I fix this?

Also, I asked this question hoping someone could tell me why this is happening as well.  Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: re "for whatever reason this site isn't printing what I want" - that would be the formatting rules of markdown and html; I have edited your question - if you click "edit", you'll be able to see how you do that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string ipCamAdd = Session["camera"].Trim().ToString();
```

For the valid concern, Session["camera"] could be null, add function such as the following to your code

> ```
>     static string ToSafeString(string theVal)
>     {
>         string theAns;
>         theAns = (theVal==null ? "" : theVal);
>         return theAns;
>     }
> ```

Then use:

> string ipCamAdd = Session["camera"].ToSafeString().Trim();

Comment: It would be even better to trim it when it goes *into* session... (perhaps both; a trim doesn't allocate a new string instance if it doesn't change anything, so no real impact)

Comment: This will break if called before the session variable is set.

Comment: The OP code would break also, as it doesn't check if the session variable exists before accessing it.

Comment: That's no reason to propose a broken solution.

Comment: It isn't a broken solution, as we don't know what all of the code and context are. The OP may very well be taking care of insuring that the session variable will exist before attempted access. It is simply something we can't know with the information given. Checking it again unnecessarily is just as bad as not checking it. We have to put a little faith in the OP.

Comment: How would I check if session exists first?

Comment: To see if Session variable exist, use Session["Camera"] !=null

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Replace` if you just want to get rid of the spaces:

```
TextBox1.Text = "http://" + (ipCamAdd ?? "").Replace(" ", "") + "/jpg/image.jpg?resolution=320x240";
```

Answer (score 1):

Trim the result before setting to session.

```
Session["camera"] = tempDV.Table.Rows[num].ItemArray[2].Trim();
```

Seems In SQL your data type is `char(*)` if you convert the data type to `varchar` and re enter data, you wont get any additional spaces